# Applying CIFilter to UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-image

In UIViewController displaying image in UIImageView. I want to display it with some special effects. Using core image.framework

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
                       initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"piano.png"]];

myImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 360);

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CIFilter *filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIVignette"];

CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"piano.png"]];

[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];

[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:18] forKey:@"inputIntensity"];

[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

[baseView addSubview:inputImage];
```

but looks like I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIImage can not be added as subview because it is not a view (UIView subclass). You need a UIImageView with a UIImage attached to its 'image' property (and this UIImage you can create from the CIImage, I believe).

Answer (score 3):

As the other post indicates, a CIImage is not a view so it can't be added as one. CIImage is really only used for doing image processing, to display the filtered image you'll need to convert it back to a UIImage. To do this, you need to get the output CIImage from the filter (**not** the input image). If you have multiple filters chained, use the last filter in the chain. Then you'll need to convert the output CIImage to a CGImage, and from there to a UIImage. This code accomplishes these things:

```
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey]; //Get the processed image from the filter

CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]; //Create a CGImage from the output CIImage

UIImage* outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage]; // Create a UIImage from the CGImage
```

Also remember that the UIImage will have to go into a UIImageView, as it's not a view itself!

For more information, see the Core Image programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html